# Do we use a plural or singular verb with "respectively"?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I need to know whether we should use singular or plural verb when we use "respectively".

Example:

> 1. Bob and Alice **has** BMW and Lexus car, respectively.
> 2. Bob and Alice **have** BMW and Lexus car, respectively.

**Question**: Which one of the above sentences is correct ?

Comment: The subject is still "Bob and Alive", regardless of the presence of respectively. Therefore, the second one is correct.

Comment: I did not mention it before, but for "MBW and Lexus car" (I suppose it's BMW), you should add an "a" before "MBW" (and eventually "Lexus" depending on what you mean), eventually dropping "car" altogether.

Answer (score 2):

The second, as the subject "Bob and Alice" is plural. The adverb doesn't change that.

It would, of course be possible to rephrase "Bob drives a BMW and Alice (drives) a Lexus". The repeated verb can be dropped.

The adverb "respectively" is sometimes misused, even where it is grammatically correct. [Grammarist.com](http://grammarist.com/usage/respective-respectively/) gives examples of good and bad use of "respective".